# SocketException . Sent to failed. Broken pipe

Tags: android, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to to be able  upload photos(blobs)  my  android application with back-end in Google App Engine.

I have done some online reading and i have deduced that i need the following.
(1) A serve let that creates the upload url (in the backend).
(2) A server let that handles response from(1) above such that i can get the blobkey of the posted image(from the response ).

(3) A class in my app(android client) to handle multi-data and invoke server let 1.
So i have serverlet 1

```
public class BlobUrlGet extends HttpServlet {

    BlobstoreService blServ = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        String blobUploadUrl = blServ.createUploadUrl("/blobupload");

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(blobUploadUrl);
    }
```

And serverlet 2.

```
public class BlobUpload extends HttpServlet {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
            .getBlobstoreService();

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            List<BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get("photo");
            BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get(0);

            ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
            ServingUrlOptions servingOptions = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);

            String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(servingOptions);

            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            resp.setContentType("application/json");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("servingUrl", servingUrl);
            json.put("blobKey", blobKey.getKeyString());

            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.print(json.toString());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Serverlet mappings

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>BlobUrlGet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.data.model.BlobUrlGet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BlobUrlGet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bloburlget</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BlobUpload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.data.model.BlobUpload</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BlobUpload</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/blobupload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And here is the code to do multi-party posting.

```
public class MultipartyUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartyUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     * @param name  field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     *
     * @param fieldName  name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     *
     * @param name  - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     *
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Here is my uploading code. This where i believe i have failed . How do i get URL for passing the paramater to the multi-data utility class?

```
private class postImageAsncTask extends  AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         try {
             MultipartyUtility multipart= new MultipartyUtility("http://mayproject-id-2016.appspot.com/_ah/api/bloburlget", "UTF-8");
             File myfile = new File(params[0]);

             multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
             multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

             multipart.addFormField("description", "Cool Pictures");
             multipart.addFormField("keywords", "Java,upload,Spring");

             multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", myfile);


             List<String> response = multipart.finish();

             System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

             for (String line : response) {
                 System.out.println(line);
             }
             return  response.toString();

         }catch(IOException e)
             {

                e.printStackTrace();
                 return  null;
             }


     }
 }
```

When i execute the code above i get the error below.

```
58:33.581 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
09-18 14:58:33.607 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:586)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:555)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:513)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:42)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:271)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:70)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:116)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:44)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RetryableSink.writeToSocket(RetryableSink.java:77)
09-18 14:58:33.608 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.writeRequestBody(HttpConnection.java:236)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.writeRequestBody(HttpTransport.java:77)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:617)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety.MultipartyUtility.finish(MultipartyUtility.java:131)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety.ReportIncident$postImageAsncTask.doInBackground(ReportIncident.java:605)
09-18 14:58:33.609 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety.ReportIncident$postImageAsncTask.doInBackground(ReportIncident.java:588)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-18 14:58:33.610 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
09-18 14:58:33.611 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
09-18 14:58:33.611 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:176)
09-18 14:58:33.611 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
09-18 14:58:33.611 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:553)
09-18 14:58:33.611 16069-17466/roadsafety.com.unra.unraroadsafety W/System.err:     ... 22 more
```

My guess is that i am not properly calling the code for uploading. Especially the servelet Url i pass to the mulit-part utility class.

Any pointers to the right direction are eagerly awaited.

Ronald

Comment: python sample: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload/blob/master/gcs_upload.py

Comment: checked it but could use it as a guide.